# GoogleChart not drawing properly

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

[image]

My Chart has a datetime value and two number values (positive and negative).

The above image shows the results of drawing one bar, datetime being current date, the problem is, the bar covers 1990 to 2050, when it should only be covering the current month.

If I draw 2 bars, one for last month, and one for current month, everything is drawn properly.

[image]

I'm assuming GoogleCharts needs at least 2 dates for some reason. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this, or give some direction.

Thanks in advance,

**Edit to ADD:**

**The Chart that I am using:**

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'controls']});
```

**The single bar that I am drawing comes from this data store in `historyChart`:**

```
[["2016-10-01T00:00:00+00:00", 5000.0, 0]]
```

**I am inserting this data to the chart in this manner:**

```
data.addColumn('datetime', 'Chart Filter');
        data.addColumn('number');
        data.addColumn('number');
        data.addRows(historyChart);
```

**The Chart wrapper and options are as followed:**

```
var programmaticChart  = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
          'containerId': 'programmatic_chart_div',
          'options': {
            displayExactValues:false,
            vAxis: {
                format: '$#,###', //add $sign in virtical axis
                viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
            },
            hAxis:{
                format: 'MMM-yyyy',
            },

            width: 900,
            height: 450,
            chartArea: {
                'backgroundColor': {
                    'fill': '#F4F4F4',
                    'opacity': 100
                 },
                top:50,
                left:85,
                width: 1000

            },
            title: "{{ member.username }}'s chart", //set user name as chart's title
            isStacked:"true",
            bar:{groupWidth: "95%"},
            colors: ['#7FFF00', '#e6693e'],

          }
        });

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        dashboard.bind(programmaticSlider, programmaticChart);
        dashboard.draw(data);
```

Comment: Some code would be appreciated. You dont even say wich chart are you using. Come on...

Comment: please share a sample of the data being used

Comment: @Mikel sorry about that, I have made an edit and added context. If you require more information let me know.

Comment: @WhiteHat I made an edit and added the single row of data that I am trying to draw with a datetime, hope this makes it more clear. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding option for `hAxis.ticks` seems to help...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('43', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Chart Filter');
    data.addColumn('number');
    data.addColumn('number');
    data.addRows([
      [new Date("10/01/2016"), 5000.0, 0]
    ]);

    var programmaticChart  = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'ColumnChart',
      containerId: 'programmatic_chart_div',
      dataTable: data,
      options: {
        displayExactValues: false,
        vAxis: {
          format: '$#,###',
          viewWindowMode: 'maximized'
        },
        hAxis:{
          format: 'MMM-yyyy',
          ticks: [new Date("10/01/2016")]
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 450,
        chartArea: {
          backgroundColor: {
            fill: '#f4f4f4',
            opacity: 100
          },
          top: 50,
          left: 85,
          width: 1000
        },
        title: '{{ member.username }}\'s chart',
        isStacked: 'true',
        bar:{groupWidth: '95%'},
        colors: ['#7fff00', '#e6693e']
      }
    });
    programmaticChart.draw();

    //dashboard.bind(programmaticSlider, programmaticChart);
    //dashboard.draw(data);
  },
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="programmatic_chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: My date's formatting is wrong?? I have 3 arrays, one of them comes from the database through my view file. This means I have to change the way the date is formatted in python, and then change it in JavaScript for the other two arrays also. This is going to be more work than I thought. Your answer clearly works, I will tick it off after attempting to find alternative (if possible). Thanks WhiteHat.

Comment: I just placed the first date in the ticks field, and it worked. I thought I needed to place all the dates in the ticks field, dumb assumption. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually never mind, I have to get all the dates in an array and place in tricks. If I put just one, then only the first date shows lol..

Comment: I copied all the dates in one array, then placed the array in the tricks field, and it did not recognize it as dates. I'm guessing unlike the chart data, the tricks field does not accept arrays?

Comment: `hAxis.ticks` should be a one dimensional array, as in the example above -- there can be as many dates as needed --> `ticks: [new Date("10/01/2016"), new Date("10/02/2016"), new Date("10/03/2016"), ...]`

Comment: The issue was, I placed the array inside the brackets -.- I just removed the brackets and it worked perfect.